# Does strong convergence in $H$ (or $L^2$) imply convergence in $V$ (or $W_0^{1,2}$)?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

Suppose:

- $\mathbf{V}$ and $\mathbf{H}$ are Hilbert spaces.
- $\mathbf{V} \hookrightarrow \mathbf{H}$ is compact embedding.
- $\mathbf{V}$ is dense in $\mathbf{H}$.

For example $\mathbf{V} = W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ and $\mathbf{H} = L^2(\Omega)$ for bounded $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $\mathbf{u}_n,\mathbf{u} \in \mathbf{V}$. It's implied from the *Rellich-Kondrachov embeddidng theorem* that bounded $\mathbf{u}_n$ in $\mathbf{V}$ has convergent subsequence in $\mathbf{H}$.

I am asking the *opposite* question:

Consider a bounded sequence $\mathbf{u}_n \in \mathbf{V}$. If $\mathbf{u}_n \to \mathbf{u}$ *strongly* in $\mathbf{H}$, does it weakly convergent in $\mathbf{V}$? Does it converge to the same $\mathbf{u}$?

A more general question:

What requirements the sequence $(\mathbf{u}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ should have in $\mathbf{H}$, so that $\mathbf{u}_n$ is

- weakly convergenent in $\mathbf{V}$?
- Strongly convergent in $\mathbf{V}$?

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111616/weak-convergence-of-l2-implies-weak-convergence-of-w-01-2-up-to-a-subse?rq=1) is a similar question, but I do not know how this is shown.

Answer (score 1):

If $(u_n)$ is bounded in $V$ and $u_n\to u$ in $H$, then $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ in $V$:

As $(u_n)$ is bounded in $V$, it has a weakly converging subsequence $u_{n_k}\rightharpoonup v$ in $V$. The continuity of the embedding into $H$ implies $v=u$ and $u\in V$.

Using this argument, one can prove that every subsequence of $(u_n)$ has a subsequence that converges weakly to $u$ in $V$. Hence $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ in $V$.

Comment: Thank you @daw. As I understood from your answer, we do not need $H$ then. As long as $u_n \in V$ is bounded, it has a weakly convergent subsequence $u_n \rightharpoonup u \in V$. Furthermore, if $u_n \to v$ in $H$, then $u = v$.

Comment: A furthure question @daw: is it a consequence of [Banach-Alaoglu theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem)?

Comment: yes to both......

Answer (score 0):

From ${u_n},u \in H$ we can't imply ${u_n},u \in V$.

Comment: I assumed $u_n \in V$, and $u_n$ strongly converge to $u$ in $H$.  I edited the question.